# Swift integer type cast to enum

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I have an `enum` declaration.

```
enum OP_CODE {
    case addition
    case substraction
    case multiplication
    case division
}
```

And use it in a method:

```
func performOperation(operation: OP_CODE) {
        
}
```

We all know that how we can call this normally

```
self.performOperation(OP_CODE.addition)
```

But if I have to call it in some delegate where the integer value is not predictable, how do I call it?

For example:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     self.delegate.performOperation(indexPath.row)
}
```

Here, the compiler throws an error `Int is not convertible to 'OP_CODE'`. I've tried many permutations, but haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to specify the raw type of the enumeration

```
enum OP_CODE: Int {
    case addition, substraction, multiplication, division
}
```

`addition` will have a raw value of `0`, `substraction` of `1`, and so on.

and then you can do

```
if let code = OP_CODE(rawValue: indexPath.row) {
    self.delegate.performOperation(code)
} else {
   // invalid code
}
```

More info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-XID_222

---

#### for older swift releases

In case you're using an older version of swift, raw enumerations work a bit different. In Xcode < 6.1, you have to use `fromRaw()` instead of a failable initializer:

```
let code = OP_CODE.fromRaw(indexPath.row)
```

Comment: Tried it. Got an error `OP_CODE cannot be constructed it has no accessible initializers`- Can you please brief it.

Comment: I might have put a typo, try now

Comment: I tried the code and it works on my side, which version of Xcode are you on?

Comment: Xcode - Version 6.0.1 (6A317) & OS X Yosemite version 10.10

Comment: that's an old version, in that case you can use `OP_CODE.fromRaw(indexPath.row)`, but you should really upgrade to 6.1

Comment: Oh man! That's why its not working. Your solution is very appreciating and thanks for pointing me out for Xcode version.

Comment: Don't forgot to set Int type to your Enum !

Answer (score 8):

You can use [raw values](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-XID_226) in your enum:

```
enum OP_CODE : Int{
    case addition = 0
    case substraction = 1
    case multiplication = 2
    case division = 3
}
```

and use the failable initializer taking a raw value as input:

```
let code = OP_CODE(rawValue: 2) // code == .multiplication
```

Note that `code` is an optional, because if the raw value doesn't map to a valid enum, the initializer returns nil.

In your case:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let code = OP_CODE(rawValue: indexPath.row)
    if let code = code {
        self.delegate.performOperation(code)
    }
}
```

Moreover, given an instance of the enum, you can obtain the associated raw value using the `rawValue` property.

Note: enums have changed a little bit in Xcode 6.1 - if you're using a previous version, read @GabrielePetronella's answer and related comments.